# How to give names of 2D arrays dynamically in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create few 2D arrays of the same size. e.g. table1[80][3], table2[80][3], table3[80][3], ..., tableN[80][3]. But the number(N) of arrays to create, will be provided by the user.
So, how can I create those arrays dynamically?
Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: I think the closest thing you can get is `std::map<std::string,std::array<std::array<int,3>,80>> tables;`.

Comment: @alain of course you can. You create an array of 2D arrays :p

Comment: Yes, a 3D array etc.. but you can't choose a name.

Comment: I don't think the issue is that he wants to name them.

Comment: Maybe, but the title goes in that direction...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Array of Dynamic Arrays in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192093/how-to-create-array-of-dynamic-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Your question is unclear: the title mentions giving each array a name, but in the question text you don't specify that they have to have names, just that the user can specify how many there are. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can't have dynamic symbol names of variables or functions in c++. These only matter during compilation of the code, and there's no way to generate them at run time of your program.

As mentioned in my comment, the closest thing you can get is to map those tables with certain `std::string` values like

```
std::map<std::string,std::array<std::array<int,3>,80>> tables;
```

and manipulate values like this

```
tables["table1"][20][1] = 0;
tables["table2"][10][0] = 42;
// etc. ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a 3d array:

```
typedef int T[80][3]; // T is your 2d array type

T* tables = new T[N]; // an array of N T's.
```

Or an amusing mixture of arrays and vectors:

```
std::vector<T> tables(N); // the same, but safer
```

Sure, these aren't *named*... but is `table1` really better than `tables[0]`? Your mileage may vary.